# ConfigServiceProvider in Laravel 5 doesn't pass the correct values to Controllers/Views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I run a query in the `ConfigServiceProvider` to set count values that I want to use throughout the application.

```
public function boot() {
    $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM property_in_property_category INNER JOIN property ON property_in_property_category.property_id = property.id INNER JOIN business ON property.business_id = business.id WHERE property_in_property_category.property_category_id = 1 AND property.active = 1 AND business.isActive = 1";
    $sale = DB::select($query);
    foreach($sale as $object) {
        $sale_array[] =  (array) $object;
    }
    $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM property_in_property_category INNER JOIN property ON property_in_property_category.property_id = property.id INNER JOIN business ON property.business_id = business.id WHERE property_in_property_category.property_category_id = 2 AND property.active = 1 AND business.isActive = 1";
    $rent = DB::select($query);
    foreach($rent as $object) {
        $rent_array[] =  (array) $object;
    }
    config([
        'for-sale' => $sale_array[0]['count(*)'],
        'for-rent' => $rent_array[0]['count(*)']
    ]);
}
```

When I run the queries in `phpMyAdmin` I get the correct values like 413 and 227 back.

But when I call these values in a view using `config('for-sale')` and `config('for-rent')`, the values are incorrect, like 446 and 239. This is on a live Linux server. When running on local (Windows) it gives me the correct values.

First I thought this may have to do with casing of names, but as the query runs well in phpMyAdmin and there is no casing in the rest of the code this is not a possibility

Comment: Why are you manually writing your queries? Eloquent will do this for you if you design your models/relationships correctly.

Comment: As Eloquent does not work in the config service provider

Comment: @AlvinBakker You can use Eloquent in your service provider if it's registered after `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class` is registered I believe.